# inconsistent literal with 4.7 g++

Tags: c++

I have quite a problem with simple defines in code. I've read about the fix from Mozilla bug site report, but it does not work in my case.

Original part of the code (of course it worked in 4.6):

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#define A "A: %20"PRIu64

error: inconsistent user-defined literal suffixes ’A’ in string literal
```

After fix:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#define A "A: %20" PRIu64

error: inconsistent user-defined literal suffixes ’A’ in string literal
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the fix?

Comment: here you go : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/9nD4Mb8pN1Q it derived exactly from this topic : http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50917

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to a later version of `g++` - both forms of your code work fine in version 5.4:

```
#include <iostream>
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#define A "A: %20"PRIu64
#define B "B: %20" PRIu64

int main() {
    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
}
```